# Why dropping folder onto an Applescript app displays a dialog?

Tags: applescript, droplet

I have an Applescript app that can receive files or folders dropped onto its icon:

```
on open theDroppedItems
    tell application "Finder"
       set droppedItemSourcePath to (the POSIX path of theDroppedItems)
       ...
```

At this point of the script, when my app receives a file or a folder, an unknown and useless Applescript application named "Droplet" displays an open file/folder dialog.
My script was compiled as application with Script Debugger 6.

I don't understand why this strange "Droplet" app asks me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that `theDroppedItems` is a **list** of `alias` specifiers even if only one file was dropped and getting the POSIX path of a list throws an error

To get all POSIX paths of the dropped items use

```
on open theDroppedItems
    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
    set droppedItemsSourcePaths to POSIX path of (theDroppedItems as text)
    set text item delimiters to TID
    display dialog droppedItemsSourcePaths buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
...
```

To process the files one by one use a loop

```
on open theDroppedItems
    repeat with anItem in theDroppedItems
      -- do something with anItem
    end repeat

...
```

Use a Finder `tell` block only if you are going to use Finder terminology.

The mentioned `Droplet` is your app.